# Custom button to mute audio play

Tags: html, audio, iframe, embed

I have the code below and am using for a html based game i am making. It delays the playing of a call in the background while the player uses an iframe to continue to play the game without interrupting the call.

```
<audio onloadeddata="var audioPlayer = this; setTimeout(function() { audioPlayer.play(); }, 1500)">
<source src="call1.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
```

My question is, how can I make a custom mute button that can be placed within the iFrame, so that when the player clicks it, it mutes the call and hides the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

Used the following code:

The HTML

```
<a href="#" id="mutebutton"><img src="mutecall.png"></a>
<div id="soundDiv">
<audio id="background_audio" onloadeddata="var audioPlayer = this; setTimeout(function() { audioPlayer.play(); }, 1500)">
<source src="call1.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
$("#mutebutton").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
var div = document.getElementById("soundDiv");
div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}); 
</script>
```

It worked just like the question asked.

When the image was clicked, it muted the audio and hid the button.